# How to only zcat files between two time durations?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, awk

## Scenario:

I've a file called abcd.log.gz.

I want to zcat only the files from time durations 17:30:00 to 18:30:00.

Currently, I zcat the entire file. Then awk the logs between two time durations which I believe is storage heavy and I've to keep doing `rm` command which is unwanted risk.

**Script to calculate logs between two time durations.**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if three arguments are provided
if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <beg_time> <end_time> <log_file>"
    exit 1
fi

beg=$1
end=$2
log_file=$3

LC_ALL=C awk -v beg="$beg" -v end="$end" '
  match($0, /[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/) {
    t = substr($0, RSTART, 8)
    if (t >= end) selected = 0
    else if (t >= beg) selected = 1
  }
  selected' "$log_file"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `zcat` on the whole file is not storage heavy (unless you write the full output to a file, which would not be what you use zcat for).

So, just pipe your zcat output to your awk, instead of first writing to a file then reading that file.

```
zcat "$log_file_gzipped" | awk '………'
```

Comment: I write entire to a new file. Didn't know this use was unintended.

Comment: Yep! The point of using zcat instead of say ungzip is that it outputs to the standard output which can directly be consumed by a program to which that is piped

Comment: Assuming the lines in the log are in time order (seems likely) and that the log does not cover multiple days, you can exit the awk early, which will also terminate the zcat, and save reading and decompressing the rest of the file. Just `if (t >= end) exit`.

Comment: in this case at least, `zcat` is just a shortcut for `gunzip -c file.gz | awk '...'` . Looking at output of `zcat --help` vs `gunzip --help` there are a few extra options in `gunzip`, but no extra options on `zcat`. (There may be other tricks that make `zcat` useful in other ways, but you'll have to research that).